# ASP.NET mvc3 webpage wont upload files to server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, file-upload

Im trying to store an category object in my db and upload an image that i can refer to this category,

The category is stored perfectly but the image is not being uploaded for some reason. When i debug i can see that my application never enters the method that stores the file on the server because my file is "Null".

model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace SkyLearn.Areas.Categories.Models
{
    public class Category
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Icon { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }

    public class CategoryDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Category> categories { get; set; }
    }
}
```

controller:

```
//
// POST: /Categories/Category/Create
[Authorize(Roles = "administrator")]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Category category, HttpPostedFileBase Icon)
{
    if (Icon != null && Icon.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        // extract only the filename
        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(Icon.FileName);
        // store the file inside ~/App_Data/uploads folder
        var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("../Content/icons/"), fileName);
        Icon.SaveAs(path);
        category.Icon = fileName;
    }

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.categories.Add(category);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");  
    }

    return View(category);
}
```

view:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<SkyLearn.Areas.Categories.Models.Category>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Create
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

<h2>Create</h2>

<script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>

<% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Category</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title) %>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Icon) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <input type="file" name="icon" id="icon"/>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description) %>
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
</form>
<% } %>

<div>
    <%: Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index") %>
</div>

</asp:Content>
```

anybody who can tell me why it wont enter the method that saves the file id be grateful.

i tried looking through the other answers here on stackoverflow and even though some of them had the same problem as me their solutions didnt solve mine.

i also tried changing the upload size etc in my config.web.

please help me :)

Comment: I don't know how browsers would treat a nested form, but there's no point in using `Html.BeginForm()` and then writing out a form tag manually.  `Html.BeginForm()` has an overload to output Html attributes: `Html.BeginForm(action, controller, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype="multipart/form-data" })`.

Comment: if you care to add that as an answer i will accept it right away. That just solved all my problems :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how browsers would treat a nested form, but there's no point in using `Html.BeginForm()` and then writing out a form tag manually. `Html.BeginForm()` has an overload to output Html attributes:

```
Html.BeginForm(action, controller, 
    FormMethod.Post, new { enctype="multipart/form-data" })
```

Answer (score 0):

The ModelBinder is probably blowing up. You can't have an input for your action method named `Icon` and also have a property on your `Category` class named `Icon` when your form is setup the way it is (all Form Values would be matched up to `Category` properties).

Also, your form field name is a lowercase "icon" and not the matching uppercase "Icon" that you have in C#

You could probably make one custom class that the action method will receive from the form post:

```
public class CategoryWithFile : Category
{
    public HttpPostedFileBase IconFile { get; set; }
}
```

Then make that the parameter on your action method

```
public ActionResult Create(CategoryWithFile category)
```

And change your form to have:

```
 <div class="editor-label">
     <label for="IconFile">Icon: </label>
 </div>
 <div class="editor-field">
     <input type="file" name="IconFile" id="IconFile"/>
 </div>
```